# How to replace parent directory in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I've the following situation:

```
SOURCES=home/main.cpp modelChecking/Configuracao.cpp modelChecking/Estado.cpp modelChecking/Formula.cpp modelChecking/ModelChecking.cpp lib/VisitTree.cpp
SUFIX=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
OBJECTS=$(SUFIX)

all: refiner
refiner: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o refiner

home/main.o: home/main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

modelChecking/Configuracao.o: modelChecking/Configuracao.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

modelChecking/Estado.o: modelChecking/Estado.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
...
```

...and so on.

As you can see, I have different directories to compile my executable.
Now, I want to put every file .o in the bin/ folder and the variable OBJECT must replace the every parent directory, and I tried different ways:

```
OBJECTS=$(SUFIX:%/ = bin/)
OBJECTS=$(subst %/,bin/,$(SUFIX))
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %/,bin/,$(SUFIX))
```

When I use something like this `$(subst home/,bin/,$(SUFIX))` it works, because I type the substring "home/", but I need of a regular expression to replace all directories.
And I'll need to change the target too, perhaps the code below will works:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

... But I prefer every target separate

Comment: Just don't. `make` pretty much assumes that input and output files will be in the same directory, except that a separate `install` step will copy files into their final destinations. Yes, you can work around that, but why should you? Go with the flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `SUFIX=$(addprefix bin/,$(notdir $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))`

The `Makefile` will look like:

```
SOURCES=home/main.cpp modelChecking/Configuracao.cpp
SUFIX=$(addprefix bin/,$(notdir $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))
OBJECTS=$(SUFIX)

all: refiner
refiner: $(OBJECTS)
     $(CC) $^ -o refiner

bin/main.o: home/main.cpp
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

bin/Configuracao.o: modelChecking/Configuracao.cpp
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

However I suggest to use `SUBDIRS` instead. Create to Makefiles

`Makefile`

```
SUBDIRS = bin
.PHONY: subdirs $(SUBDIRS)
subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

`bin/Makefile`

```
SOURCES=../home/main.cpp ../modelChecking/Configuracao.cpp
SUFIX=$(addprefix bin/,$(notdir $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))
OBJECTS=$(SUFIX)

all: refiner
refiner: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o refiner

main.o: ../home/main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

Configuracao.o: ../modelChecking/Configuracao.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

This way you will not have to worry about object prefix.